# Google Analytics for mobile and server-side caching

Tags: caching, mobile, google-analytics

I need to implement Google Analytics for a mobile site that is behind a CDN. This means that every page of content (including any tracking pixel references) is going to be cached for anywhere between 15 seconds and 5 minutes. I see that the GA tracking code implements a random number (`utmn`) in constructing the pixel, possibly to distinguish separate requests, separate users or simply to bust their own cache.

Does anyone know if it is safe to leave the page content cached? (I assume it is) Will we lose much tracking data?

Also, is it safe to serve the `ga.aspx` pixel itself from the CDN (where it would get cached) or does each GA pixel URL need to be uniquely addressed?

Does anyone have any recommendations on how best to implement GA? Server load from traffic is a huge concern for us, but we also want accurate numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The mobile code will not work properly unless the utmn is generated for each call, so if you can serve the content so that it won't get cached (on server side), that would solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. The domain it's coming off is the CDN (our servers wouldn't be able to handle the traffic on heavy days if it wasn't), so all content will always be cached. I wonder if Google changed their documentation since I asked my question. It now says about `utmn`, "Unique ID generated for each GIF request to prevent caching of the GIF image". This really sounds to me like client-side caching (which doesn't bother me). I'm mainly worried about two different devices getting the exact same html content, but getting counted as one hit.

Comment: It's been that way, but unfortunately it only applies to JavaScript, on the mobile version (which is a hack to emulate GA JS) you still would run to the problem of devices (or operators/proxies) caching GA GIF (once per page etc. combo, so not as bad as it sounds). The device info etc. is read on Google's end when the receive the request, so that won't get affected.